# Graph of a list of rules with coefficient

Tags: graphs-and-networks, pattern-matching, rule

I am trying to transform an expression to a list of rules and after that plot its graph. The expression has the following form

```
num \[LeftAngleBracket] fi[a,x], fi[c,y] \[RightAngleBracket] \[LeftAngleBracket] fi[b,x],fi[a,x] \[RightAngleBracket] \[LeftAngleBracket] fi[a,y],fi[b,x] \[RightAngleBracket]
```

By using the below substitution

```
/. \[LeftAngleBracket] fi[a_,x_], fi[b_,y_] \[RightAngleBracket] -> KroneckerDelta[a, b] UndirectedEdge[x, y]
```

I get

```
num (KroneckerDelta[a, b])^2 (UndirectedEdge[x, y])^2 UndirectedEdge[x, x]  KroneckerDelta[a, c]
```

**Here begins the main point of my question.** My challenge is to separate the UndirectedEdge terms and create a list of them for plotting a graph. The other terms in the expression must appear as the factor of the Graph. In fact, I want to get something like this

```
num (KroneckerDelta[a, b])^2   KroneckerDelta[a, c] {UndirectedEdge[x, y],UndirectedEdge[x, y], UndirectedEdge[x, x]}
```

I tried the command

```
Cases[%, _UndirectedEdge | _Power]
```

that delivers a list of rules as follow

```
{(UndirectedEdge[x, y])^2 , UndirectedEdge[x, x]}
```

but the power of UndirectedEdge ruins the result for the Graph command. 
I would appreciate any light on this problem.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are doing. Can you provide working code? `<a>` is not valid syntax. It's also not clear to me why you are trying to do arithmetic on `UndirectedEdge`. It makes no sense to do that. It would help if you explained the problem in plain language (rather than try to explain your non-working solution attempt), and then illustrate it with [a _simplified_ but complete example](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks very much for your attention. I made some changes into my question. I hope it be more clear now. In fact, I'm not doing arithmetic on `UndirectedEdge`. The Mathematica automatically transforms `UndirectedEdge[x,y] UndirectedEdge[x,y]` into `(UndirectedEdge[x,y])^2`.

Comment: You are multiplying together `UndirectedEdge` expressions, which makes no sense. In this example it is explicit: `KroneckerDelta[a, b] UndirectedEdge[x, y]`. Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Szabolcs, this multiplication is the result of the substitution, in the second code. Resuming, In the beginning I have an expression like f[x] <a,b><a,b><b,c>. I would like to transform it to f[x] {UndirectedEdge[a,b] , UndirectedEdge[a,b] , UndirectedEdge[b,c]}. Then I can make a plot of the Graph inside the list.

Comment: Not just the substitution, you are explicitly including yet another multiplication on the LHS of the rule. Why don't you just use `Cases` instead of trying to put UndirectedEdge in arithmetic expressions (where it does not belong)? Use the 3rd argument of `Cases` with `Infinity` to search at all levels.

Comment: @Szabolcs, thanks very much for your hint! Instead of using a substitution directly, I used `Cases` with `Infinity`. This method solved my problem. In this way I can factor out the coefficient of `UndirectedEdge`s.